# how to generate special numbers?

Tags: java

I need to generate the first 20 numbers that are prime which starts with one and the second digit is three.
I know how to check if a number is prime but I am finding a difficulty in the other part.

Also can somebody give me more exercises on generating some numbers having a special characteristic please because I am finding a difficulty  in them. thank you

```
  public static int isprime(int x){
         for(int i=2;i<x;i++)
               if(x%i==0)
                  return false;
        return true;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start, your `isPrime()` method could be a little more efficient. There's no point checking for factors beyond the square root of the number since, if they exist, you would have found their partner already *below* the square root. Hence you can make the continuation condition of the `for` statement into something like:

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= x; i++)
```

You can also roughly double the speed by only checking odd numbers after the `2`.

Assuming they don't get too big, you can just convert them to a string and see if it starts with `"13"`.

In Java, `Long.toString()` and `String.startsWith()` are likely to be the best tools for the job.

If you want to tackle that on your own, then go do that now, since I provide a full solution below.

---

Still here? I assume then that you've either tried, or you just want a solution.

See, for example, the following program:

```
public class Test {
    public static boolean isPrime (long num) {
        if ((num % 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (long chk = 3; chk * chk <= num; chk += 2) {
            if ((num % chk) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (long num = 2, count = 0; count < 20; num++) {
            if (Long.toString(num).startsWith("13")) {
                if (isPrime(num)) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println ("#" + count + ": " + num);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which generates:

```
#1: 13
#2: 131
#3: 137
#4: 139
#5: 1301
#6: 1303
#7: 1307
#8: 1319
#9: 1321
#10: 1327
#11: 1361
#12: 1367
#13: 1373
#14: 1381
#15: 1399
#16: 13001
#17: 13003
#18: 13007
#19: 13009
#20: 13033
```

---

One *final* bit of optimisation may increase the performance if you're after large numbers, like the first two million rather than the first twenty.

To do this we start with `13` then, whenever your number starts with `14`, you can skip a chunk of candidates (like `14` through `129` inclusive, or from `140,000` through to `1,299,999` inclusive).

This ensures that you're only checking numbers that begin with `13` in the first place, such as `13`, `130-139`, `1,300-1,399`, `13,000-13,999` and so on. You can also speed things up by only checking the odd numbers. The use of partial number checks also means that we don't *need* to do string conversions, we revert to numeric-only operations which is likely to be beneficial.

To do that, make the following changes to the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static boolean isPrime (long num) {
        if ((num % 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (long chk = 3; chk * chk <= num; chk += 2) {
            if ((num % chk) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (long num = 13, end = 14, count = 0; count < 2000000; num += 2) {
            // Code to move from 140..0 to 1299..9

            if (num >= end) {
                end = end * 10;
                num = (end / 14) * 13 - 1;
                continue;
            }
            if (isPrime(num)) {
                count++;
                System.out.println ("#" + count + ": " + num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This reduces runtime for the first two million numbers from 394 seconds to 323 seconds, a drop of 18%.

Comment: Also, to multiply the integer `n` with 10, use `Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n) + "0")`…  But was it really necessary to deprive the OP of the chance to do its own homework?

Comment: @5gon12eder, OP can _still_ do their own homework, if indeed it _is_ homework, rather than just self-education. Nobody's forcing people here at gunpoint to copy code :-) I prefer my answers to be as complete as possible so as to help the widest possible audience. I'm not entirely certain of your intent with the `* 10` comment since (1) I don't do that and (2) surely it's easier to just `n = n * 10`?

Comment: @5gon12eder: but I'll modify the answer to make clear the delineation between the "guiding a learner" bit, and the "giving an answer" bit. It's then up to the reader to decide in which camp they fall. Hope that helps.

Comment: I see your point and it is a valid one though mine is a bit different here.  Anyway, discussing this belongs on Meta (where is actually *is* discussed a lot).  Hope you didn't mind me mentioning it.  The “how to multiply with 10” was just joking on the looking at the string representation to figure out the digits.  See my answer for what I've had in mind instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your problem, the output is `[13, 131, 137, 139, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 13001, 13003, 13007, 13009, 13033]`

But it is ok because you have small numbers. If you wanted the 2000M first numbers, it wouldn't be the best way to go.

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(20);
    int i = 13; // We know that it's not ok before ;)
    while (res.size() < 20) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            char[] chars = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
            if (chars[0] == '1' && chars[1] == '3') {
                res.add(i);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}


// You had an error in your method
private static boolean isPrime(int x) {
    for (int i = 2; i < x; i++)
        if (x % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Two thousand is a doddle at 0.093 seconds. Even two _hundred_ thousand only takes about 15 seconds for me, keeping in mind that's with my squaring version of the `for` loop. Two million is about where I got tired of waiting, but it eventually finished after 394 seconds, or about six and a half minutes.

Comment: Yes I forgot to put a big number when I wrote the answer. Your version is modre optimized that's true. We could also only generate numbers that start with "13" to skip all the irrelevant numbers. But I think the best way to go is in the answer of @5gon12eder. It depends on the context but it feels like an exercise so the mathematical answer could be a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In decimal representation, the second digit of a *d*-digit number *n* is 3 if and only if the last digit of the decimal representation of *n* div 10<sup>*d − 2*</sup> is 3.  The last digit of the decimal representation of a number *m* is 3 if and only if *m* mod 10 = 3.

See this example:

> *n* = 13759 has a *d* = 5 digit decimal representation.  *n* div 10<sup>*d* − 2</sup> = 13759 div 10<sup>3</sup> = 13759 div 1000 = 13 = *m*.  Since *m* mod 10 = 13 mod 10 = 3, the second digit of *n*'s decimal representation was indeed 3.

Likewise, the first digit of the decimal representation of a *d*-digit number *n* is 1 if and only if *n* div 10<sup>*d* − 1</sup> = 1.

What is left to do is figuring out how many digits the decimal representation of a number has.  I'll only give you the following hint:  If *n* ≥10 has a *d*-digit representation, then *n* div 10 has a (*d* − 1)-digit representation.  Also, for *n* <10, the decimal representation has always 1 digit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the number to a string and check the first and second character.

```
public static boolean hasOneAndThree(int n){
    String nString = Integer.toString(n);
    if(nString.length() >= 2){
        if (nString.charAt(0) == '1' & nString.charAt(1) == '3'){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, I believe that isprime is supposed to return a boolean, not an integer. So,

```
public static boolean isprime(int x){
     for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
           if(x%i==0)
              return false;
    return true;  
}
```